Белые полосы на тайлах при передвижении Unity 2D
При передвижении возникают полосы/рябит изображение (движение происходит при помощи смены гравитации  разные стороны), не могу решить проблему долгое время, все способы, которые я нашел или смог реализовать не помогли, надеюсь на вашу помощь.
Ссылка на видео с проблемой:
https://files.fm/u/mv5pm7n8cp
Что пробовал:

Настройка pixel per units, размеры тайлов соответствуют размерам пикселей изображения
Настройки камеры: ort size соответствует четному количеству тайлов
На всех тайлах стоит Point no filter, я также пробовал все остальные варианты фильтрации
Также пробовал отключать сглаживание, это не помогло
Я пробовал не использовать тайлсет и грид в целом, та же рябь появляется и на простых спрайтах
Я закинул спрайты в атлас спрайтов, как вы понимаете, результата нет
Дело не в коллайдерах, при их отключении ничего не меняется
Пробовал перерисовывать тайлы, делать их сплошными, никаких изменений нет


Мне помогло в настройках самого спрайта, который впоследствии разбит на тайлсет, поставить Generate Mipmaps.
После этого я закинул спрайт с тайлами в спрайт атлас, и проблема была решена.
Качество немного упало, и, в общем-то, получилось не совсем то, что я ожидал увидеть, но выглядит все еще хорошо.
Скрин с настройками:

